# Error using Javascript dot notation

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts

I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` at the `date` line. Removing `.setHours(this.getHours()-6)` it runs just fine but I need to offset for timezone purposed. In this case CST or -6 hours. I believe I am misusing dot notation. As a note `AmCharts.stringToDate(` is returning a `Date` object.

```
var lineChartData = [
    {
        date: AmCharts.stringToDate("2014-04-18 13:44:39", "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS").setHours(this.getHours()-6),
        ambUp: 67.21,
        ambDown: 62.83,
        ext: 47.75,
        in: 44.15,
        out: 44.38,
        freeze: 23.45,
        fridge: 46.29,
        diff: 2.14,
        diff2: 0.2250 
    },
];
```

Comment: **Note:** You have a trailing comma after your object declaration. That is invalid (or at least very bad to use) in JavaScript.

Comment: @jsve: it's not invalid, but older IE versions will throw an error. I haven't heard that it is bad practice though, if you don't have to support older IEs.

Comment: Definitely not invalid, and definitely not "bad to use". The ability to have a trailing common is very useful when you're needing to add/remove properties frequently while coding. It's really too bad that JSON doesn't allow a trailing comma. I'm sure Crockford didn't allow it purely to accommodate IE so that `eval()` could be used. Very unfortunate.

Comment: @FelixKling I learn something new every day... Here's an interesting article: http://dontkry.com/posts/code/trailing-commas.html. It seems to be saying exactly what you say.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like `this` is not what you think it is. There is no special scope in properties like that, you should use an extra variable to reference the date twice

```
var date = AmCharts.stringToDate("2014-04-18 13:44:39", "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS");
date.setHours(date.getHours() - 6);

var lineChartData = [{
    date: date,
    ambUp: 67.21,
    ambDown: 62.83,
    ext: 47.75,
    in : 44.15,
    out: 44.38,
    freeze: 23.45,
    fridge: 46.29,
    diff: 2.14,
    diff2: 0.2250
}];
```